# Parsing XML via jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, xml

UPDATED:
I need to pass the "game id #" to the jQuery parse function.  The game information needs to be displayed at various points in my HTML.  What am I missing?  Do I need to modify my css?  Or am I just going about this in a wrong direction?  Any help is more than welcomed.

HTML

```
<div class="matchR1-wrapL">
     <game id='1'></game>
</div>
```

CSS

```
teamL, winnerL, loserL{
    float: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 135px;
    text-align: left;
    height: 1em;
}
winnerL{
      font-weight: bold;
}
loserL{
    color: #888;
}
.matchR1-wrapL{
    float: left;
    border-top: 1px solid #999;
    border-right: 1px solid #999;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #999;
    background: #ECECEC;
    width: 149px; 
    height: 2em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

jQuery - UPDATED

```
xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml );
$xml = $( xmlDoc ); 

$($xml).find('tournament').each(function(){
 var gameNum = $('game').attr('id');
 var home = $(this).find("home").text();
 var away = $(this).find("away").text();
 var winner = $(this).find("winner").text();
 var loser = $(this).find("loser").text();
  if(home == winner){
   $("game").html( "<matchNumL> " + gameNum + "</matchNumL> <winnerL> " + home + " </winnerL> <loserL> " + away + "</loserL>");
   }
 else if(away == winner){
   $("game").html( "<matchNumL> " + gameNum + "</matchNumL><loserL> " + home + " </loserL> <winnerL> " + away + "</winnerL>" );
   }
  else
   $("game").html( "<matchNumL> " + gameNum + "</matchNumL> <teamL> " + home + " </teamL> <teamL> " + away + "</teamL>" );    
});
```

XML examples...

```
<tournament>      
    <game id="2">
    <home>Jamaica</home>
    <away>Beermuda</away>
    <winner>Beermuda</winner>
    <loser>Jamaica</loser>
</game>
<game id="3">
    <home>Rockaway</home>
    <away>Mexico</away>
    <winner>Winner Game 3</winner>
    <loser>Loser Game 3</loser>
</game>
<game id="4">
    <home>Argentina</home>
    <away>Cuba</away>
    <winner>Winner Game 4</winner>
    <loser>Loser Game 4</loser>
</game>
</tournament>
```

Comment: Without seeing the xml it's impossible to say whether or not your parsing is correct, but you need to wrap your strings in quotes before going any further.  I'd suggest checking the browser console for errors and fixing them before trying to go any further.  Also, `gameInfo` is not a jQuery object so using `.text()` is wrong.  Just use the string variable.

Comment: how stupid of me.  completely forgot to post that... updated original post.  In that instance of Game 02, Beermuda would become bold, and Jamaica would become grey

Comment: Use `gameInfo.append("<div etc..")`

Comment: You're not wrapping you're HTML in quotes. Look at the gameInfo += lines, the HTML in those need to be in quotes

Comment: OK I appreciate the help thus far, updated the  jQuery script in the main post.  Maybe I am missing something and/or over-complicating this... but how can I reference just a single "game" from my XML file and have it return the proper data and style.  i.e. i only want to display the information on game 3...

Comment: Your XML is invalid, you may have only a single root node.

Comment: XML is, in fact, valid...i only pasted a sample of the file to give a point of reference

Comment: here is a jsfiddle of my updated code.  only issue if parsing by game number to display the proper game information.
http://jsfiddle.net/jVQLE/